# Why is Palladium-108 "theoretically capable of spontaneous fission?"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, radiation, elements, isotopes

I was just reading [Wikipedia's page on palladium isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_palladium#cite_note-SF-13) and I noticed the note about Palladium-108. It says "theoretically capable of spontaneous fission", but I don't find that explained anywhere. the same note is on other isotopes of palladium, as well. So, I am just asking if someone could explain the note.

For example, how do we know it's capable of spontaneous fission? What makes it capable of spontaneous fission? And why is it still called stable instead of just giving it a half life absurdly long like 9.9x10^100 or something? Thanks for the help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a reaction is theoretically possible or not is determined, firstly, by the $Q$ of the reaction. For nuclear reactions, $Q$ is the mass energy of the difference in reactant nuclear mass and product nuclear mass. If $Q$ is positive, the reaction is possible, as long as other conservation laws aren't violated.

With spontaneous fission, the reaction would be something like $$A\to B+C+Xn,$$
with $A$, $B$, $C$ being specific nuclides and $X$ being the number of neutrons. If you calculate the $Q$ for $^{108}$Pd splitting equally or near equally (1 proton high, 1 proton low), you will get a positive $Q$ close to $10$ MeV. So SF is theoretically possible, but for some reason it's inhibited, probably because the fission activation energy is too high. So, we don't observe it in reality.

This is similar to the case of alpha decay for $^{208}$Pb. It's theoretically possible, but the $Q$ is so small that the predicted halflife ( $2.6\times 10^{21}$ years) indicates we would probably never observe it, and the predictive model is not accurate enough to publish a value.

Comment: I understand 2.6×10^21 is an unimaginably long time, but there are unimaginably many atoms too. I was wondering, if we took 1 cubic meter of lead-208 ~11,340 kg ~ 3.29×10^28 atoms, how long would it take for one of the atoms to decay?

Comment: @JimmyG. under your conditions, the activity would be about 1 per 3.6 s. Alpha decay means we wouldn't detect the alpha (buried somewhere inside the lead), and if there was a gamma the activity would be well below background levels.

Comment: So in practice we can't measure the decay, but in principle can we? I mean, what if an outside atom decays? Would that be able to be picked up?

Comment: @JimmyG. I believe that that $2.6\times 10^{21}$ years is a experimentally determined lower limit; the actual half-life may be much longer: the three predicted value for $^{208}\mathrm{Pb}$ have a geometric mean at the order of $10^{126}$ years in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.11458.pdf). Using the data from this article, we can see that among those observationally stable nuclides, only $^{149}\mathrm{Sm}$ and $^{187}\mathrm{Os}$ (at the order of $\sim 10^{18}$ years and $\sim 10^{17}$ years respectively) have reasonable half-lives that offer a possibility to detect alpha decay.